# Rendering rapidly-changing arbitrary-sized meshes with Metal and Swift 3

Tags: swift3, triangulation, metal, frame-rate, render-to-texture

I am trying to  render random meshes to an MTKView as fast as the device will allow.. Pretty much all the metal examples I have found show how to draw a piece of geometry for which the buffer size is defined only once (i.e. fixed):

```
let dataSize = vertexCount * MemoryLayout<VertexWithColor>.size // size of the vertex data in bytes
let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer = device!.makeBuffer(bytes: verticesWithColorArray, length: dataSize, options: []) // create a new buffer on the GPU
```

The goal is to eventually generate meshes on the fly given some point cloud input.  I've set up drawing to be triggered with  a tap as follows:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first  {
      let touchPoint = touch.location(in: view)
      print ("...touch \(touchPoint)")

      autoreleasepool {
        delaunayView.setupTriangles()
        delaunayView.renderTriangles()
      }
    }
  }
```

I can get the screen to refresh with new triangles, as long as I don't tap too frequently.  However, if I tap too quickly (like say a double tap), the app crashes with the following error:

```
[CAMetalLayerDrawable texture] should not be called after presenting the drawable.
```

Performance will obviously be linked to the number of triangles drawn. Besides getting the app to function stably, just as important is the question, how can I best take advantage of the GPU to **push as many triangles as possible?**  (In its current state, the app draws about 30,000 triangles at 3 fps on an iPad Air 2).

Any pointers/gotchas for speed and frame rate  would be most welcome

The whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/plutovman/MetalDelaunayTriangulation):

Also, below is the pertinent updated metal class

```
import Metal
import MetalKit
import GameplayKit

protocol MTKViewDelaunayTriangulationDelegate: NSObjectProtocol{  
  func fpsUpdate (fps: Int)
}

class MTKViewDelaunayTriangulation: MTKView {

  //var kernelFunction: MTLFunction!
  var pipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState!
  var defaultLibrary: MTLLibrary! = nil
  var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue! = nil
  var renderPipeline: MTLRenderPipelineState!
  var errorFlag:Bool = false

  var verticesWithColorArray : [VertexWithColor]!
  var vertexCount: Int
  var verticesMemoryByteSize:Int

  let fpsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 20))
  var frameCounter: Int = 0
  var frameStartTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()


  weak var MTKViewDelaunayTriangulationDelegate: MTKViewDelaunayTriangulationDelegate?

  ////////////////////
  init(frame: CGRect) {

    vertexCount = 100000
    //verticesMemoryByteSize = vertexCount * MemoryLayout<VertexWithColor>.size
    verticesMemoryByteSize = vertexCount * MemoryLayout<VertexWithColor>.stride // apple recommendation
    super.init(frame: frame, device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice())

    setupMetal()
    //setupTriangles()
    //renderTriangles()
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  /*
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    step() // needed to update frame counter

    autoreleasepool {
      setupTriangles()
      renderTriangles()

    }

  } */


  func step() {
    frameCounter += 1
    if frameCounter == 100
    {
      let frametime = (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - frameStartTime) / 100
      MTKViewDelaunayTriangulationDelegate?.fpsUpdate(fps: Int(1 / frametime)) // let the delegate know of the frame update
      print ("...frametime: \((Int(1/frametime)))")
      frameStartTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() // reset start time
      frameCounter = 0 // reset counter
    }
  }

  func setupMetal(){

    // Steps required to set up metal for rendering:

    // 1. Create a MTLDevice
    // 2. Create a Command Queue
    // 3. Access the custom shader library
    // 4. Compile shaders from library
    // 5. Create a render pipeline
    // 6. Set buffer size of objects to be drawn
    // 7. Draw to pipeline through a renderCommandEncoder


    // 1. Create a MTLDevice
    guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else {
      errorFlag = true
      //particleLabDelegate?.particleLabMetalUnavailable()
      return
    }

    // 2. Create a Command Queue
    commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()

    // 3. Access the custom shader library
    defaultLibrary = device.newDefaultLibrary()

    // 4. Compile shaders from library
    let fragmentProgram = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "basic_fragment")
    let vertexProgram = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "basic_vertex")

    // 5a. Define render pipeline settings
    let renderPipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    renderPipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexProgram
    renderPipelineDescriptor.sampleCount = self.sampleCount
    renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = self.colorPixelFormat
    renderPipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentProgram

    // 5b. Compile renderPipeline with above renderPipelineDescriptor
    do {
      renderPipeline = try device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: renderPipelineDescriptor)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("render pipeline error: " + error.description)
    }

    // initialize counter variables
    frameStartTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    frameCounter = 0

  } // end of setupMetal

  /// Generate set of vertices for our triangulation to use
  func generateVertices(_ size: CGSize, cellSize: CGFloat, variance: CGFloat = 0.75, seed: UInt64 = numericCast(arc4random())) -> [Vertex] {

    // How many cells we're going to have on each axis (pad by 2 cells on each edge)
    let cellsX = (size.width + 4 * cellSize) / cellSize
    let cellsY = (size.height + 4 * cellSize) / cellSize

    // figure out the bleed widths to center the grid
    let bleedX = ((cellsX * cellSize) - size.width)/2
    let bleedY = ((cellsY * cellSize) - size.height)/2

    let _variance = cellSize * variance / 4

    var points = [Vertex]()
    let minX = -bleedX
    let maxX = size.width + bleedX
    let minY = -bleedY
    let maxY = size.height + bleedY

    let generator = GKLinearCongruentialRandomSource(seed: seed)

    for i in stride(from: minX, to: maxX, by: cellSize) {
      for j in stride(from: minY, to: maxY, by: cellSize) {

        let x = i + cellSize/2 + CGFloat(generator.nextUniform()) + CGFloat.random(-_variance, _variance)
        let y = j + cellSize/2 + CGFloat(generator.nextUniform()) + CGFloat.random(-_variance, _variance)

        points.append(Vertex(x: Double(x), y: Double(y)))
      }
    }

    return points
  } // end of generateVertices

  func setupTriangles(){

    // generate n random triangles
    ///////////////////
    verticesWithColorArray = [] // empty out vertex array

    for _ in 0 ... vertexCount {
      //for vertex in vertices {
      let x = Float(Double.random(-1.0, 1.0))
      let y = Float(Double.random(-1.0, 1.0))
      let v = VertexWithColor(x: x, y: y, z: 0.0, r: Float(Double.random()), g: Float(Double.random()), b: Float(Double.random()), a: 0.0)

      verticesWithColorArray.append(v)
    } // end of for _ in



  } // end of setupTriangles

  func renderTriangles(){
    // 6. Set buffer size of objects to be drawn
    //let dataSize = vertexCount * MemoryLayout<VertexWithColor>.size // size of the vertex data in bytes
    let dataSize = vertexCount * MemoryLayout<VertexWithColor>.stride // apple recommendation
    let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer = device!.makeBuffer(bytes: verticesWithColorArray, length: dataSize, options: []) // create a new buffer on the GPU
    let renderPassDescriptor: MTLRenderPassDescriptor? = self.currentRenderPassDescriptor

    // If the renderPassDescriptor is valid, begin the commands to render into its drawable
    if renderPassDescriptor != nil {
      // Create a new command buffer for each tessellation pass

      let commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer? = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
      // Create a render command encoder
      // 7a. Create a renderCommandEncoder four our renderPipeline
      let renderCommandEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder? = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor!)
      renderCommandEncoder?.label = "Render Command Encoder"
      //////////renderCommandEncoder?.pushDebugGroup("Tessellate and Render")
      renderCommandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipeline!)
      renderCommandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, at: 0)
      // most important below: we tell the GPU to draw a set of triangles, based on the vertex buffer. Each triangle consists of three vertices, starting at index 0 inside the vertex buffer, and there are vertexCount/3 triangles total
      //renderCommandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertexCount, instanceCount: vertexCount/3)
      renderCommandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertexCount)

      ///////////renderCommandEncoder?.popDebugGroup()
      renderCommandEncoder?.endEncoding() // finalize renderEncoder set up

      commandBuffer?.present(self.currentDrawable!) // needed to make sure the new texture is presented as soon as the drawing completes

      // 7b. Render to pipeline
      commandBuffer?.commit() // commit and send task to gpu

    } // end of if renderPassDescriptor 

  }// end of func renderTriangles()


} // end of class MTKViewDelaunayTriangulation
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `setupTriangles()` or, especially, `renderTriangles()` from `init()`. Also, as a side issue, use `MemoryLayout<…>.stride`, not `.size` when calculating allocation sizes. See the [`MemoryLayout` docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/memorylayout).

Comment: You should omit the `instanceCount` parameter in your draw call. It doesn't do what you think it does, and it's causing your GPU to do way more work than necessary.

Comment: Thank you@KenThomases.  That seems to have fixed the problem.  I notice however that I get the same error if I call setUpTriangles() and renderTriangles() via touchesBegan--if I tap too repeatedly.  How would I account for user-driven updates? (I updated the question above)

Comment: @warrenm: Thank you. It does run much faster without the instanceCount setting.  Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: @Plutovman The number of primitives to render is inferred from the vertex count (or index count, in the case of indexed drawing). The instance count parameter determines how many times the entire mesh is drawn (you can differentiate among instances in your vertex shader by attributing a parameter with [[instance_id]], which allows you to position and otherwise customize each instance). In your case, since you're only drawing one mesh per draw call, the `instanceCount` parameter should be 1, or omitted entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `setupTriangles()` or, especially, `renderTriangles()` from `init()`. Nor, as per your comment, from `touchesBegan()`. In general, you should only attempt to draw when the framework calls your override of `draw(_:)`.

How you update for user events depends on the drawing mode of the [`MTKView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metalkit/mtkview), as explained in the class overview. By default, your `draw(_:)` method is called periodically. In this mode, you shouldn't have to do anything about drawing in `touchesBegan()`. Just update your class's internal state about what it should draw. The actual drawing will happen automatically a short time later.

If you've configured the view to redraw after `setNeedsDisplay()`, then `touchesBegan()` should update internal state and then call `setNeedsDisplay()`. It shouldn't attempt to draw immediately. A short time after you return control back to the framework (i.e. return from `touchesBegan()`), it will call `draw(_:)` for you.

If you've configured the view to only draw when you explicitly call `draw()`, then you would do that after updating internal state.

Comment: Crystal clear. Thank you.  I've updated the [project](https://github.com/plutovman/MetalDelaunayTriangulation) to reflect the changes